# Targeting input box in a external web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, target, popupwindow

I'm fairly new programmer and i need an advice how i can make this possible,

my goal is to be able to open a new website in a new window for example google.com and enter a string into the search input box without the user having to do anything.

I have looked many ideas how this would be implemented but don't seem to find a solution i can use.

I made a button that triggers this javascript function:

```
function OpenPopupCenter() {
     pageURL = 'http://www.google.com';
     title = 'temp title';
     w = (window.outerWidth * 0.67);
     h = (window.outerHeight * 0.80);

    var dualScreenLeft = typeof window.screenLeft !== "undefined" ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
    var dualScreenTop = typeof window.screenTop !== "undefined" ? window.screenTop : screen.top;

    var width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth :
    document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
    var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight :
    document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

    var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft -125;
    var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;
    var newWindow = window.open(pageURL, title, 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

    $(newWindow).ready(function () {
        $("#lst-ib").val("Hello World");
    });
```

The window opens up displaying google but I'm unable to target the input box by the id lst-ib and inserting the string "Hello World" into it, am i doing it wrong and can anyone direct me to the right solution or come up with one that might work.

Comment: This sounds like a task that would violate JavaScript cross-domain policies, so it might not be doable. Keep in mind that a website that could control another site could get access to something sensitive like banking information or emails. Maybe the "fake" takeover seen on the site "Let Me Google That For You" can be inspiring for what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario this is not possible due to the [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Quoting the relevant information:

> Under the policy, a web browser permits scripts contained in a first web page to access data in a second web page, but only if both web pages have the same origin

This is for security reasons. Without the policy, anyone could (for example) write a script that opens up your bank account website and transfers them all of your money.

Answer (score 0):

Here. When **Google** wants to search something, it uses a **base url**: http://google.com/search?q= . What it's searching for goes after the **'='**, substituting the **[spaces]** with **'+'**. If I wanted to look up **'Genetic Algorithm'**, I'd strip the spaces and replace them with **'+'** so, it becomes **'Genetic+Algorithm'**. I then would **join** this with the base url, so 'http://google.com/search?q=Genetic+Algorithm' would be the final result. There are other things you can besides **'search?q='**, like adding **'&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa'** to the end makes it do an image search. There are many different tags you can use for different purposes. I hope this helps.